# Read email from MS Exchange using Java EWS

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am trying to create a simple program to read emails in my company's MS Exchange inbox.
I wrote a simle program as below, but it does not work.

Can someone guide me, what is wrong here?
I tried both with Autodiscovery and URL mode.

When I run the program I see the following output:

```
111111111111111 Aug 08, 2014 12:37:12 AM
org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor
selectAuthScheme INFO: NTLM authentication scheme selected Aug 08,
2014 12:37:12 AM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
processWWWAuthChallenge INFO: Failure authenticating with NTLM <any
realm>@autodiscover.<cmpany>:443
```

The program:

```
package com.experiment;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.FindItemsResults;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.Item;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.ItemView;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.WellKnownFolderName;

public class MSOutlookIntg {
    private static final String EMAIL_ID = "myid@company.com";
    private static final String EMAIL_PWD = "mypwd";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(EMAIL_ID, EMAIL_PWD);
        service.setCredentials(credentials);



        try {
            System.out.println("111111111111111");
            service.autodiscoverUrl(EMAIL_ID);
            //service.setUrl(new URI("https://<email-server>/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
            service.setTraceEnabled(true);
            System.out.println("222222222222222");
            ItemView view = new ItemView(10);
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;

            findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, view);

            for(Item item : findResults.getItems())
            {
                item.load();
                System.out.println(item.getSubject());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move `service.setTraceEnabled` into the first line after `ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2)`. The full trace is the key to successfully debugging the problem.

Btw. I had to implement a trace listener on my own. Do you have a working trace listener attached to service? Without that, setTraceEnabled won't be of much help.

Have you tried with "EnableScpLookup"?

In my case, setting EnableSCPLookup to True never was a problem. It could need a few milliseconds until no appropriate SCP record was returned, but most of the time it saved me 20 seconds(!) to wait for the web server at `https://autodiscover.company.com` to time out because of https certificates (server waiting for a client certificate and client waiting for the server's reply...).

And furthermore, what error came in URL mode? It can't be the same, because you should not get an "autodiscover" error when circumventing autodiscover...

EDITh says that you should check whether your email is the same as your UPN name. I think your credentials have to contain the UPN name, not the email? It is not completely clear from the Microsoft docs, since Microsoft chose the UPN to match the email address.